# Windows CopyFilesDialog multiple files, no folder

Tags: file, progress

In my WPF app, I want to copy files using Copy Files Dialog builded in windows. I have found I can do it by: Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyFile, but the problem is I don't know how to copy many files using this dialog. The same as windows provides. You may select SOME files from a folder, copy them, and one Copy Files Dialog is shown. How can I achieve it - copying many files with ONE dialog, one after another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the native `SHFileOperation` provided by windows, have a look here:

[C# does Shell, Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell2.aspx)

then on MSDN you can also find this about Windows Vista:

[IFileOperation Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775771.aspx)

> Exposes methods to copy, move, rename, create, and delete Shell items
>   as well as methods to provide progress and error dialogs. This
>   interface **replaces** the SHFileOperation function.

Those are exactly the Dialogs built in windows as you asked, it requires a bit of work to use them but is the only way you are sure that moving your application to another operating system you will always use the latest features (for windows 8 improvements on those dialogs see here: [Windows 8 Explorer: improved copy, delete, and conflict resolution](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/93822-windows-8-explorer-to-feature-improved-copy-move-delete-and-conflict-resolution))

Comment: One more question. Than what do you suggest me to use? C# does Shell, Part 2 or IFileOperation Interface? Do I undearstand it right? IFileOperation Interface is only for Vista? Which would be easier?

Comment: do you plan to only have Win7 or Vista clients or are you fine to state your software requires Vista at minimum? Then you have the answer already, if you want to support WindowsXP go for the classic way, still supported in Vista anyway.