# c# copy multiple files

Tags: c#, file-copying

I try to copy multiple files in c# from Folder A to Folder B. I filter the files I want to copy in my Code - after that for example the files 1 , 2 and 5 from Folder A should copy to Folder B. 
Therefor I want to use the Windows Copy Gui - because I want to see the the copy Progress bar and the Options if any file with the same already name exist.

I´ve found "[How to bring up the built-in File Copy dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687443/how-to-bring-up-the-built-in-file-copy-dialog)" this article. And I´ve tried to work with the following Options:

Filesystem.CopyFile
Filesystem.CopyDirectory

But my Problem is: If I use CopyFile I only can copy ONE File... If I start the CopyFile Statement in loop the Windows Copy GUI will open and close for every file so I cant use the progressbar.

If I use CopyDirectory I only can Copy all files from Folder A to Folder B.

So how can I copy multiple files from Folder A to Folder B with using the WINDOWS COPY GUI ???

Thank you.

Comment: perform for loop or foreach maybe this is the way

Comment: The Problem is if i copy the files in a loop or foreach the Filesystem.Copy Funktion will start and open/close the Windows Copy GUI for every file separately

Comment: first select files and get all selected File Name or Path then store in array and run loop on array and copy files from folder a to b

Comment: I think it probably would be the best to write your own GUI, which shouldn't be too complicated.

Comment: @MetaColon - I have thought About it, but it must be possible ? I mean if I select some files in Explorer and start copying files the Windows Copy GUI do

Comment: This has to be possible, or Windows wouldn't be able to do it.  The best I've found when looking into it is summed up in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371342/windows-copyfilesdialog-multiple-files-no-folder Looks like you may end up having to implement a decent amount on your own I'm afraid. Sorry don't really have time right now to give an example on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using VB.Net wrapper over native Windows API and the wrapper limits you. Probably, you can use those (or newer API's) directly and should search into 
I think you need to use [IFileOperation.CopyItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-copyitems), which accepts array of items as a source, but you'll have to write lots of interop code or find other samples.

Comment: Okay sorry for my Question .. but i cant find some Details About "IFileOperation.CopyItems" ? Maybe you can tell me where I can find an example Code how to use ?

Comment: @Sunnyboy.94 I found another SO question with link to source code using that interface. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418080/c-sharp-ifileoperation-how-to-get-status-and-error-information-for-all-operation Hopefully that would be a good starting point.